# Is the abortion of someone outside the Chatur Varna sinful?

Tags: dharma, varna, parashara-smriti

Not a duplicate of [What is Hinduism's view on abortion?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15904/what-is-hinduisms-view-on-abortion), because it is on abortion in general.

In the linked question a lot of the answers saying abortion is immoral/sinful simply do not make sense to be immoral/sinful for someone outside the Chatur Varna e.g. an outcast can't become an outcast again, "those born in consequence of an illegal mixture of the castes," don't get the libations of water anyway, someone outside the Chatur Varna cannot lose caste, etc. Others have to be in brief otherwise they would lead to nonsense conclusions like Rama went to Hell for hunting deer.

Ironically the scripture that seems to be the harshest critic of abortion has the most glaring issue with abortion being sinful outside the Chatur Varna. The Parashara Smriti says this which seems to be straightforward anti-abortion:

> What sin is incurred in killing a Brahman, abortion
> causes a sin twice as great ; there is no atonement for that
> sin. The abandonment of such a woman has been ordained
> by law.

The Parashara Smriti says a similar thing for cows that killing a fully formed cow fetus twice as bad as killing a cow. This shows the Parashara Smriti really considers killing a fully formed fetus twice as bad as killing the born version of that thing. That has to leave out people outside the Chatur Varna, because **there is no sin mentioned in Hinduism for killing someone outside the Chatur Varna (anymore than the life you kill on a daily basis)**. That's honestly for the best, because of cancer.

> If all the members of the foetus are complete, or if
> it be observed to have consciousness, or fully developed
> in its limbs, large and small — then the sinner must perform
> twice the penance for killing a cow.

Does anyone have a scripture saying against abortion of a child outside the Chatur Varna, that is clearly not in brief due to nonsense conclusions?

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp064.htm
https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf_djvu.txt

Comment: Duplicate. as answered in a previous question with upanishad reference, scripture says a jiva enters the womb at conception. Its not a question of the development of the outer sheath, the annamaya kosha.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Did you not see my point about killing someone outside the Chatur Varna not being declared sinful (more than the life you kill on a daily basis) or did you choose to ignore it?

Comment: > there is no sin mentioned in Hinduism for killing someone outside the Chatur Varna

- are you joking ? murder is a sin. The punishments vary though.

Comment: @mar Where does scripture say that (except for a general statement of not harming all beings)? The Manu Smriti specifies sin for killing all the Chaturvarna, but nothing for Dasyus.

Comment: @mar Many people translate Dasyu outside the Manu Smriti to mean thieves, which avoids their killing extending to nonaggressors. However, that does not work with the Manu Smriti.

Comment: @mar Also the only way you can get to murder is always a sin and make it make sense is if you have a nonsense definition of a human. One that does not fit the biological definition and requires a crazy God that conditionally gives souls to fit human preconceptions, but not to stop world hunger or anything useful.

Comment: murder of innocents is always a sin. murder of criminals is not. God does not and will not stop world hunger. it's like saying God should solve the 'earning problem' - where people have to work to earn money.

Comment: @mar I'm not saying he should solve world hunger. I'm saying if he is bothered enough to create an unnatural soul system to align with human sensibilities, he can solve world hunger (by avoiding children destined to starve being born) while he is at it.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa - "(by avoiding children destined to starve being born)" - free will is more important than any perceived good (or bad) by God. Those who want free will to decide their own fate - good or bad, alone play in the game of samsara. What you're saying is like *"Why did the referee not prevent the player from committing a foul in the first place? Why let him commit a foul and then give him a red card. Makes no sense"*. Fine, then don't play. Others will continue playing

Comment: @mar Why is free will only important for morality? Why is the free will of life to live in ways that don't align with human sensibilities also important?

Comment: Your words and their associated meanings don't seem to be in alignment, probably because you're making unnecessarily complicated sentences. Break it down into simple english and the answers are also usually simple enough. Who said free will is important only for morality? What does human sensibilities even mean?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you believe the context of the [Manu Smriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201775.html). The Manu Smriti says that Dasyu means anyone outside the Chaturvarna.

> मुखबाहूरुपद्जानां या लोके जातयो बहिः ।
> म्लेच्छवाचश्चार्यवाचः सर्वे ते दस्यवः स्मृताः ॥ ४५ ॥
>
> mukhabāhūrupadjānāṃ yā loke jātayo bahiḥ |
> mleccavācaścāryavācaḥ sarve te dasyavaḥ smṛtāḥ || 45 ||
>
> All those races of the world which are outside the pale of the people ‘born of the mouth, the arms, the thighs and the feet,’—speaking the ‘barbaric’ or the ‘refined’ language—are called ‘Dasyu.’—(45)

References to exterminating the Dasyus appear in a few places, one of the most obvious is [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv09088.htm).

> Like Pedu's horse who killed the brood of serpents, thus thou, O Soma, **slayest every Dasyu**.

Since the Vedas are asking for it, it seems not to be sinful to kill a Dasyu, according to the Manu Smriti. Thus the sin for aborting one, which is twice that of killing a grown one, as discussed in the question, is also negligible. Thus, it is not sinful to abort someone outside the Chaturvarna. Probably for the best with all the technical murdering of the failed embryos in childbirth, cancers, non-organ donating (because they are technically still controlled by their original soul, even if severely disabled (don't worry, I doubt they can feel strong boredom without a brain)), etc. everyone does without feeling guilty.