# What does Hinduism says about earning anything through wrong means but using it for the benefit of others?

Tags: karma, dharma, sin, punyam, adharma

Example -
A police man takes bribe(not his choice, but due to circumstances) from someone but he uses the money for good things like some charity, donations, feeding poor etc.

So is it a papa or punya? What does hinduism say on this?

Comment: If the tags are not appropriate, then please change them. I did not get anything even after thinking so much.

Comment: In the Lalitopakhyana, it is mentioned that a person used money obtained via theft to build temples, so he neither reached svarga (due to using ill-gotten wealth) nor fell down in hell(due to the act of financing the construction of a temple), instead he was condemned to remain as a ghost for certain period of time (better than being cast in hell, worse compared to reaching svarga).

Comment: One would rather not indulge in bribery, as any avoidance is not going to cause a highly  detrimental / miserable consequence. So avoidance is supposed to be the act of dharma.
However, a stone-blind adherence, may not be a recommendation ,as an act of  Dharma is  context  sensitive. The following may relate to the topic in question .
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200246.html

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52065/saving-dharma-and-saving-lives

Comment: @Athrey I don't want to know only about bribery..I gave that as only an example...I want to know about ANY bad means..

Comment: Thank you @AnubrataBit . Is this true for both cases..I mean taking from his will and taking against his will?

Comment: @LSSJBroly , In my understanding , an act of dharma is context sensitive,(papa and punya is reaped accordingly),also the Intention behind the action has stake over papa /punya. I hope the links ,are to some extent related to the topic .

Comment: @AnubrataBit , thanks for the quotation , from laitopakyana

Comment: Thank you @Athrey

Comment: if you steal money and donate some of that to temple, that money goes into pocket of trustee who steals donations from that temple. i.e. bad source go to bad destination. we hear about corruption in temples all the time, and we wonder why bhagavan allows corruption even in his own abode. that's because the corrupt input money needs some proper outlet - and that outlet is into the hands of corrupt people.

Comment: Okay @mar but what if someone gets something forcefully..I mean due to circumstances and not from his own will and then using it for good purpose and not for selfish needs. Then what happens does it count as papa or punya?